# letting switch stmt run with no result, or checking the switch var type to not trigger it in the 1st place

Tags: javascript

I've made a chat bot for my uni group, which gives you schedule based on input msg. In bots logic there's a weekday var, which represents... well, the week day. But it could be both an int and a string, depending on user input.
First, i check if there's a specific day in the input msg and assign the correct string value to my var.
If there's none, i get current date and day of the week as an int value, and using switch statement assign the right string to it aswell.
The thing, that got me thinking, is there're 2 ways i could use the switch stmt.
First is checking the var type, and only then executing

```
if(typeof weekday == "number"){
```

Second is just letting it run with no result to come

```
switch (weekday){
    case 1:weekday = "monday";
        break;
    case 2:weekday = "tuesday";
        break;
    case 3:weekday = "wednesday";
        break;
    case 4:weekday = "thursday";
        break;
    case 5:weekday = "friday";
        break;
    case 6:weekday = "saturday";
        break;
    case 0:weekday = "sunday";
        break;
}
```

I know it does like a milisec of difference, and noone would bother, but for the sake of knoledge, optimization and out of pure curiosity, what is faster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering a case where the `weekday` would be having a `string` value.

**For if case :** It will check if type is `"number"` and will return `false`, and will not execute further.

**For switch case :** It will check against all the 7 cases, if they match, and because it's a string, nothing will be done.

It's not hard to guess which one saves time...

Comment: well, i didnt know how switch case works exactly, from what i know, it jumps to the correct case